# Vim syntax highlight certain lines

Tags: vim, php

I have php files well any file type in general that I would like vim to highlight here docs sections using a different syntax highlighting.

```
<?php
echo <<<HTMLDOC
<h1> I am highlighted as html </h1>
<<<HTMLDOC

echo 'High Lighted as PHP again '
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can tweak the colors of course but try this:

```
:highlight MyHereDoc ctermbg=green guibg=green
:match MyHereDoc /<<<\([A-Za-z]*\)\_.*\1/
```

Also, if you plan on it being something more perminant in your vimrc add:

```
highlight MyHereDoc ctermbg=green guibg=green
matchadd("MyHereDoc", '<<<\([A-Za-z]*\)\_.*\1')
```

Comment: TY I will try it as soon as I get the chance.